# “@php_bin@” is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I am using http://phpdox.de/getting-started.html. Trying to configure it to generate API documentation of my project.

My wamp server & php is installed in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.14 folder.

And I want to implement inside G:\website\pe-gold3\documentor\phpdox folder.

I have downloaded the package from https://github.com/theseer/phpdox inside G:\website\pe-gold3\documentor\phpdox folder.

Downloaded phpdox.phar file and paste it inside G:\website\pe-gold3\documentor\phpdox folder.

Created composer.json is already installed inside C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.14 folder.

Created phpdox.xml file inside G:\website\pe-gold3\documentor\phpdox folder.

Trying to run phpdox command but it gives the given error:'"@php_bin@"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Please do let me know what should I do to configure it and get the api documentation of my project.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried `which php_bin`?

Comment: No. Can u pls tell me what I have to do and where I have to change? Pls, elaborate.

Comment: Start with the [tour]. Then, read [ask]. Finally, in order to reduce your problem further, extract a [mcve]. You've done lots of things, many being unclear and your job is to first find out which of them are actually relevant. Sorry, but welcome to Stack Overflow nonetheless!